# Run time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the below snippet in my VBA code. I see the bold line in the below code highlighted when I try to run the code. Need some help.

```
Set FldrWkbk = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & Curr_File, False, True)

 'Open new data file

Sheets("Request-Form").Range("E48").Copy

'Copy data from specific Range

Workbooks("SLG Master Report.xlsm").Activate

**Sheets(1).Cells(outputRow, OutputCol).Select**

ActiveSheet.Paste

OutputCol = OutputCol + 1
```

Comment: Supply the code, reading what you provided makes no sense because you haven't shown all the code.

Comment: please specify what is your input, what is the expected output, and ahat you are getting instead

Answer (score 0):

If either `outputRow` or `OutputCol` are `0` you will get this error as there is no row `0` or column `0` in the sheet. The first cell in the sheet is `Cells(1,1)`

Note that numerical variables are initialized as `0`. So you would need to have assigned them a value of `1` or more.

If you step through the code pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> you will execute the code line by line. When the error occurs, if you then hover over `outputRow` or `OutputCol` you will see their current values. You could also open the [locals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/locals-window) window and inspect their values there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the worksheet you are selecting from activated?

This should work as well and its a bit cleaner

```
Sheets("Request-Form".range("E48").copy_
Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(outputrow,outpotCol)
```

Comment: Since worksheets are on different workbooks you need to specify the workbook as well.